# TestComplete - ObjectSpy could not identify objects in Windows Vista/Windows 8

Tags: testcomplete

I am using TestComplete 9.3. In Windows Vista/Windows 8, when I try to access object details using ObjectSpy, I can select only outer frame of an application and not the specific element in the UI. Somehow, the other elements do not appear.

But in Windows 2K8, I can identify all the objects using ObjectSpy. Is there any setting that needs to be done for Windows Vista/Windows 8?

Please assist on the same.

Comment: Which is the application that you are trying to spy on ? Is it a Web application or a Desktop application ?

Comment: Please go through the link http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55201/, if your question is not answered i would suggest you to contact the SmartBear Support

Comment: We found the trick - Here is the link.
http://community.smartbear.com/nwkab66374/attachments/nwkab66374/Functional_Web_Testing/22279/1/DuplicateField.png

Comment: Actually, this is not a good solution in a general case. Please let us know in which browser you work with your application and what the application type is: HTML, Flex, Silverlight, Java Applet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, testing web application requires installing Chrome of Firefox patches (depending on what browser you are using) in TestComplete. Please refer to the following pages to find the patches, as well as to learn the browser versions that are supported by TestComplete 9.30:

Firefox patches: http://support.smartbear.com/downloads/testcomplete/firefox-patches/

Chrome patches: http://support.smartbear.com/downloads/testcomplete/chrome-patches/